# Restrict Sql User do not access any other databases and any other objects other than granted views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i need to create some views and i need to allow user ( login ) to access views only which are granted for him, i used fallowing script.

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN [MYLogin] WITH PASSWORD = 'Password@123'
USE [TEST]
CREATE USER [MYUser] FROM LOGIN [MYLogin]
CREATE ROLE [MYUserRead]
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'MYUserRead','MYUser'
GO
CREATE VIEW viGetA
AS
  SELECT * from dbo.A
GO 
GRANT SELECT ON viGetA TO [MYUserRead]
GO
```

i am able to view only views which granted when i login with above created user account MYLogin , but i am able to see master database, other databases (even though i am unable to access objects from user created databases ) but i am able to access sys views and sys procedures of Test database and master databases.

How can i restrict user to not to see any other databases like master,temp, MyDatabse ..etc and any system objects (sys views, DMVs ) when use login into management studio.

Please help us to provide script to users can able to see only one database and only views which are granted for that user role.

Please check below image for reference.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

To hide all databases from all users, you should deny the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission explicitly.

This will "hide" all databases from the [MYLogin]:

```
USE MASTER
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [MYLogin];
GO
```

Of course, you can deny/grant the permission to any database login individually.
If you do it for the `PUBLIC` server role, that will hide all databases from all users. Be careful with it tho!

> ALWAYS TEST PERMISSION CHANGES IN A NON-PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT FIRST!

System views are different and they are also needed to run SQL Server or other applications (such as SSMS) to run correctly, however you can try to deny select on the entire `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema.

```
DENY SELECT ON SCHEMA::sys TO [MYLogin]
DENY SELECT ON SCHEMA::INFORMATION_SCHEMA TO [MYLogin]
```

However this might cause SSMS to not load any information about the database/objects available in the database.

> ALWAYS TEST PERMISSION CHANGES IN A NON-PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT FIRST!

You can also deny `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` in the database for the user to prevent it to see the view definition (the select behind the view).